# Intellisense suggestions not showing even with correct types

Tags: typescript, webstorm, intellisense

It seems that I have a correct type in the popup preview, however, the Code Completion (intellisense) suggestions only show one attribute `id`.
The interfaces are not exported from the file they are defined in, however, even when I exported them, the behavior didn't change.

In WebStorm:

[image: only id shows in suggestions]

Correct type hints:

[image: correct type shown in popup]

**EDIT**:

I have a `Model` class, which takes 2 type generics:

```js
export default class Model<TAttributes = unknown, TEmbeds = unknown> {
    attributes: TAttributes & { id: number }
    embeds: TEmbeds & {}
```

This class is then used in `ApiResponse`:

```js
export class ApiResponse<T extends Model> {

    private readonly items: T[]

    constructor(response: IApiResponse, model: { new(...args: any[]): T; } | null) {
        this.items = model ? response.items.map(item => new model(item)) : response.items


getStatic(): (T['attributes'] & T['embeds'])[] {
        const staticItems: (T['attributes'] & T['embeds'])[] = []

        for (const item of this.items) {

            const staticItem =
                {
                    ...item.attributes,
                    ...item.embeds,
                }

            staticItems.push(staticItem)
        }

        return staticItems
    }
}
```

When I access the data from the `getStatic()` method, I would expect WebStorm to show suggestions for all attributes of the interfaces of the model, however, only `id` is shown.

**Edit 2**:
I noticed that when I hover over the `getStatic()` method, WebStorm says that the return type is `any[]`. However, when I opened the project in VsCode, it shows the correct type generics & the Code Completion (intellisense) suggestions work correctly there as well.
Is this a WebStorm bug then?

```
// WebStorm - hover
ApiResponse<T extends Model<unknown, unknown>>.getStatic(): any[]

// VsCode - hover
(method) ApiResponse<T extends Model<unknown, unknown>>.getStatic(): (T['attributes'] & T['embeds'])[]
```

Comment: `The interfaces are not exported from the file they are defined in` That won't work, they need to be exported in order to be available through Intellisense... Can you try this on [Stacblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) too see if it works there?

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: @jcalz I would be happy to replace them, I just don't know how. Should I make an ascii art of the user interface?  Even the link you sent mentions that "Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."
This is about user interface, isn't it?

Comment: @Cuzy I updated the question with code examples. The project is quite large so I couldn't test it on StackBlitz very well, however, I noticed one small difference between WebStorm and StackBlitz: when I hover over the `getStatic()` method in WebStorm, a return type `any[]` is shown: `ApiResponse<T extends Model<unknown, unknown>>.getStatic(): any[]`, however, on StackBlitz, it shows the type generics: `(method) ApiResponse<T extends Model<unknown, unknown>>.getStatic(): (T['attributes'] & T['embeds'])[]`